# Why Pascal's law is applicable for ideal gases?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, ideal-gas

Pascal's law is about incompressible fluids. But ideal gases are compressible. Still, Pascal's law is applicable to ideal gases as far as I know (might be wrong). Why is it applicable for ideal gases?

Comment: If by "Pascal's law" you mean the uniformity of pressure for an ideal gas that comes about because it is assumed that "ideal" means besides $U=U(T)$ it is also homogeneous and isotropic and the molecules do not interact with each other nor with the wall except via an elastic collision. Of course, a transient motion of the piston temporarily disturbs the uniformity and isotropy of the fluid but once the fluid has settled in its equilibrium state those get restored.

Comment: While deriving the equation of pressure for an ideal gas we use the concept of pascal's law that pressure is exerted by the gas is equal in every direction. In that situation why are we using that concept because pascal's law was about incompressible fluids, but ideal gas isn't incompressible

Comment: Oh another question i have in mind. That is while deriving the equation of pressure initially we determine the amount of force exerted by a molecule on a particular wall using newton's second law. In that case we use the time period between two consecutive collision. Why do we do that I mean why do we take that time period? Is that for determining average force exerted on the wall?

Comment: Who says it applies only to incompressible fluids?  Pascal's law (as you describe it) applies to any fluid in static equilibrium.

Comment: Found that incompressible part in wikipedia.....i might have misunderstood

Comment: If wikipedia said that, they are mistaken.